# What parts of a web application should be moved to a WorkerRole in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, cloud, soa

What parts of a web application should be moved to a WorkerRole in Azure?

I see clear uses for a website that say, converted mp3s but what about run of the mill ASP.NET site? Should CRUD operations (for example) now be handled by a WorkerRole?

Answer (score 1):

While this has been answered numerous times before in other SO questions: Web and Worker roles are essentially instances of Windows Server 2008 with or without IIS enabled. When thinking about moving tasks to a Worker Role (or even another Web Role), it comes down to performance and scaling.

If you feel that your background operations would be consuming large amounts of memory and CPU, and potentially impacting Web site performance, then move those operations to a different role and scale that role independently. You can then use Azure Queues to create work items for the different role to consume (or use a WCF service on an internal endpoint, Service Bus, or other techniques).

Combining tasks into a single Web Role will save on initial costs, as you can deploy with just one or two instances total. You'll just have to scale everything lockstep at that point.